# MySQL Unknown column in where clause error #1054

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT oNum AS orderNumber,
       cBillState AS Province
FROM orders
WHERE oNum IN ( '1482775424-189',
                ‘1482776094-127’,
                ‘1477536593-991’,
                ‘1479730802-590’,
                ‘1479920877-558’,
                ‘1479096422-217’,
                ‘1474903184-228’,
                ‘1477957959-648’,
                ‘1479275004-578’,
                ‘1480541117-247’,
                ‘1477092301-713’,
                ‘1477312082-716’,
                ‘1477398916-226’,
                ‘1477403920-962’,
                ‘1477413634-609’,
                ‘1477930535-606’,
                ‘1477955076-686’,
                ‘1478135196-101’,
                ‘1478276590-532’,
                ‘1478844924-162’,
                ‘1479359912-609’,
                ‘1479622476-128’,
                ‘1479623938-210’,
                ‘1479906995-505’,
                ‘1480054418-376’,
                ‘1480111928-502’,
                ‘1480125336-888’,
                ‘1480301567-671’,
                ‘1480365466-580’,
                ‘1480894281-609’,
                ‘1480949109-398’,
                ‘1479601155-364’,
                ‘1474307070-332’,
                ‘1480087806-183’,
                ‘1482787698-750’,
                ‘1469897352-353’,
                ‘1473537581-471’,
                ‘1473687519-991’,
                ‘1475351809-812’,
                ‘1476142232-535’,
                ‘1478902709-989’,
                ‘1482417573-419’,
                ‘1477361844-758’,
                ‘1480100297-559’,
                ‘1480994046-164’,
                ‘1478300763-269’,
                ‘1480056585-606’,
                ‘1480074372-121’,
                ‘1480380512-849’,
                ‘1480405548-219’,
                ‘1480945372-748’,
                ‘1480959346-958’,
                ‘1480979054-867’,
                ‘1480980513-214’,
                ‘1481068320-986’,
                ‘1481076087-716’,
                ‘1481305524-603’,
                ‘1481480028-875’,
                ‘1481733768-915’,
                ‘1480087091-948’,
                ‘1480439466-561’,
                ‘1482763826-493’,
                ‘1482905975-834’,
                ‘1486316457-550’,
                ‘1480018760-249’,
                ‘1479928546-617’,
                ‘1483471273-517’,
                ‘1484169298-747’,
                ‘1484190999-915’,
                ‘1477317500-446’,
                ‘1477971665-384’,
                ‘1478569145-467’,
                ‘1481561486-205’,
                ‘1481689248-289’,
                ‘1481689989-374’,
                ‘1482282006-867’,
                ‘1482425612-195’,
                ‘1482676243-627’,
                ‘1483240226-156’,
                ‘1483460319-161’,
                ‘1483465666-256’,
                ‘1486316720-332’,
                ‘1478731802-207’,
                ‘1482277678-164’,
                ‘1483984301-786’,
                ‘1483992584-520’,
                ‘1484020909-291’,
                ‘1480727936-335’,
                ‘1486869590-934’,
                ‘1483982035-667’,
                ‘1484018163-438’,
                ‘1484150283-139’,
                ‘1487613741-802’,
                ‘1483970473-109’,
                ‘1483974079-586’,
                ‘1483975971-790’,
                ‘1483978751-271’,
                ‘1483979075-338’,
                ‘1483983445-537’,
                ‘1483986171-592’,
                ‘1483986950-713’,
                ‘1483988578-641’,
                ‘1484019809-263’,
                ‘1484151424-647’,
                ‘1484171587-685’,
                ‘1484346681-146’,
                ‘1484509930-508’,
                ‘1484527687-400’,
                ‘1484757246-834’,
                ‘1486260387-326’,
                ‘1485277917-300’,
                ‘1487089945-259’,
                ‘1487300427-391’,
                ‘1487698559-786’,
                ‘1484418776-342’,
                ‘1480321037-286’,
                ‘1484262618-505’,
                ‘1484284655-434’,
                ‘1484447124-365’,
                ‘1482762650-132’,
                ‘1482851934-153’,
                ‘1482867677-237’,
                ‘1482956401-918’,
                ‘1484240287-695’,
                ‘1484445267-706’,
                ‘1484561817-854’,
                ‘1485565268-372’,
                ‘1487424684-789’,
                ‘1487467448-150’,
                ‘1488060650-455’,
                ‘1488066992-331’,
                ‘1488149236-354’,
                ‘1484063475-593’,
                ‘1484157094-588’,
                ‘1484859843-314’,
                ‘1485545522-819’,
                ‘1486516436-973’,
                ‘1486964775-771’,
                ‘1483145436-669’,
                ‘1483391592-704’,
                ‘1483502985-747’,
                ‘1483983727-219’,
                ‘1484023314-852’,
                ‘1484081233-200’,
                ‘1484322973-466’,
                ‘1484342291-447’,
                ‘1484406059-583’,
                ‘1484411015-328’,
                ‘1484425064-479’,
                ‘1484452295-582’,
                ‘1484515700-540’,
                ‘1484627708-335’,
                ‘1484632746-862’,
                ‘1485052037-249’,
                ‘1485128964-286’,
                ‘1485190492-888’,
                ‘1485195733-900’,
                ‘1485202785-384’,
                ‘1485216462-233’,
                ‘1485222790-976’,
                ‘1485357911-246’,
                ‘1485459961-895’,
                ‘1485483263-818’,
                ‘1485542911-608’,
                ‘1485568582-415’,
                ‘1485630460-879’,
                ‘1481134322-151’,
                ‘1484703008-980’,
                ‘1485846056-687’,
                ‘1484025532-550’,
                ‘1484066421-733’,
                ‘1484077460-592’,
                ‘1484149227-959’,
                ‘1484162618-303’,
                ‘1484420681-353’,
                ‘1484665197-540’,
                ‘1484755505-933’,
                ‘1484848858-607’,
                ‘1485217578-110’,
                ‘1485316847-965’,
                ‘1485567177-164’,
                ‘1485635160-954’,
                ‘1485713147-552’,
                ‘1485727727-861’,
                ‘1485868390-528’,
                ‘1485978054-311’,
                ‘1485995204-154’,
                ‘1486050211-126’,
                ‘1486232357-429’,
                ‘1483563899-665’,
                ‘1484482619-909’,
                ‘1487036669-169’,
                ‘1487531819-670’,
                ‘1489680045-522’,
                ‘1487607030-673’,
                ‘1487792756-848’,
                ‘1489592492-867’,
                ‘1485976581-271’,
                ‘1489762699-587’,
                ‘1489823936-264’,
                ‘1486680384-909’,
                ‘1490636775-210’);
```

Comment: do you have a column with that name in your database ?

Comment: Your quotes are incorrect.

Comment: Are those values actually stored in that way in the database ? string or integer ?

Comment: Stick to using these quotes ' instead of ‘ and ’ in your queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT oNum AS orderNumber,
       cBillState AS Province
FROM orders
WHERE oNum IN ( '1482775424-189',
                '1482776094-127',
                '1477536593-991',
                '1479730802-590',
                '1479920877-558',
                '1479096422-217',
                '1474903184-228',
                '1477957959-648',
                '1479275004-578',
                '1480541117-247',
                '1477092301-713',
                '1477312082-716',
                '1477398916-226',
                '1477403920-962',
                '1477413634-609',
                '1477930535-606',
                '1477955076-686',
                '1478135196-101',
                '1478276590-532',
                '1478844924-162',
                '1479359912-609',
                '1479622476-128',
                '1479623938-210',
                '1479906995-505',
                '1480054418-376',
                '1480111928-502',
                '1480125336-888',
                '1480301567-671',
                '1480365466-580',
                '1480894281-609',
                '1480949109-398',
                '1479601155-364',
                '1474307070-332',
                '1480087806-183',
                '1482787698-750',
                '1469897352-353',
                '1473537581-471',
                '1473687519-991',
                '1475351809-812',
                '1476142232-535',
                '1478902709-989',
                '1482417573-419',
                '1477361844-758',
                '1480100297-559',
                '1480994046-164',
                '1478300763-269',
                '1480056585-606',
                '1480074372-121',
                '1480380512-849',
                '1480405548-219',
                '1480945372-748',
                '1480959346-958',
                '1480979054-867',
                '1480980513-214',
                '1481068320-986',
                '1481076087-716',
                '1481305524-603',
                '1481480028-875',
                '1481733768-915',
                '1480087091-948',
                '1480439466-561',
                '1482763826-493',
                '1482905975-834',
                '1486316457-550',
                '1480018760-249',
                '1479928546-617',
                '1483471273-517',
                '1484169298-747',
                '1484190999-915',
                '1477317500-446',
                '1477971665-384',
                '1478569145-467',
                '1481561486-205',
                '1481689248-289',
                '1481689989-374',
                '1482282006-867',
                '1482425612-195',
                '1482676243-627',
                '1483240226-156',
                '1483460319-161',
                '1483465666-256',
                '1486316720-332',
                '1478731802-207',
                '1482277678-164',
                '1483984301-786',
                '1483992584-520',
                '1484020909-291',
                '1480727936-335',
                '1486869590-934',
                '1483982035-667',
                '1484018163-438',
                '1484150283-139',
                '1487613741-802',
                '1483970473-109',
                '1483974079-586',
                '1483975971-790',
                '1483978751-271',
                '1483979075-338',
                '1483983445-537',
                '1483986171-592',
                '1483986950-713',
                '1483988578-641',
                '1484019809-263',
                '1484151424-647',
                '1484171587-685',
                '1484346681-146',
                '1484509930-508',
                '1484527687-400',
                '1484757246-834',
                '1486260387-326',
                '1485277917-300',
                '1487089945-259',
                '1487300427-391',
                '1487698559-786',
                '1484418776-342',
                '1480321037-286',
                '1484262618-505',
                '1484284655-434',
                '1484447124-365',
                '1482762650-132',
                '1482851934-153',
                '1482867677-237',
                '1482956401-918',
                '1484240287-695',
                '1484445267-706',
                '1484561817-854',
                '1485565268-372',
                '1487424684-789',
                '1487467448-150',
                '1488060650-455',
                '1488066992-331',
                '1488149236-354',
                '1484063475-593',
                '1484157094-588',
                '1484859843-314',
                '1485545522-819',
                '1486516436-973',
                '1486964775-771',
                '1483145436-669',
                '1483391592-704',
                '1483502985-747',
                '1483983727-219',
                '1484023314-852',
                '1484081233-200',
                '1484322973-466',
                '1484342291-447',
                '1484406059-583',
                '1484411015-328',
                '1484425064-479',
                '1484452295-582',
                '1484515700-540',
                '1484627708-335',
                '1484632746-862',
                '1485052037-249',
                '1485128964-286',
                '1485190492-888',
                '1485195733-900',
                '1485202785-384',
                '1485216462-233',
                '1485222790-976',
                '1485357911-246',
                '1485459961-895',
                '1485483263-818',
                '1485542911-608',
                '1485568582-415',
                '1485630460-879',
                '1481134322-151',
                '1484703008-980',
                '1485846056-687',
                '1484025532-550',
                '1484066421-733',
                '1484077460-592',
                '1484149227-959',
                '1484162618-303',
                '1484420681-353',
                '1484665197-540',
                '1484755505-933',
                '1484848858-607',
                '1485217578-110',
                '1485316847-965',
                '1485567177-164',
                '1485635160-954',
                '1485713147-552',
                '1485727727-861',
                '1485868390-528',
                '1485978054-311',
                '1485995204-154',
                '1486050211-126',
                '1486232357-429',
                '1483563899-665',
                '1484482619-909',
                '1487036669-169',
                '1487531819-670',
                '1489680045-522',
                '1487607030-673',
                '1487792756-848',
                '1489592492-867',
                '1485976581-271',
                '1489762699-587',
                '1489823936-264',
                '1486680384-909',
                '1490636775-210');
```

To fix your problem I simply used global search-and-replace's to replace all occurrences of `‘` and `’` with `'`.

This is a common error in programming.  Some versions of SQL, and other languages, allow "other" single-quotes to be used in the same context as `'`, but as a rule you should avoid them unless you have a specific reason to use them and know that you can in that environment.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been racking my brain trying to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After the first value in your 'In' clause, you are using the character ‘ rather than '.